# How do I recover a deleted Spotify play list?

Tags: spotify

I accidentally deleted a play list in Spotify, and now I regret it.

It was pretty highly customized. Is there any way I can get it back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is definitely possible! Spotify provides a great answer on its [FAQ page](https://support.spotify.com/us/learn-more/faq/#!/article/can-i-recover-a-deleted-playlist):

> Accidentally deleted your favorite playlist? Don't worry, it’s easy to get it back:
>
> 1. Log in to your account at Spotify.com
> 2. Click [Recover playlists](http://www.spotify.com/us/account/recover-playlists).
> 3. Click Restore for the playlist you want to recover.
> 4. Open your Spotify app or the Web Player. The playlist will be at the bottom of your playlist collection.